# The location of .config for geotiler on Windows

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

I'm working in jupyter notebook on Windows with matplotlib basemaps and I want to use geotiler with the basemaps. I'm writing a program and as part of it, it will generate a map and plot data points on it. However, the maps that my code generates often are over a small part of the world and have no defining features. My solution was to import the geotiler library and display it over the map with an alpha so the maps generated would be identifiable. However, when I use the geotiler.Map() function, I get a message saying that the configuration file does not exist.

---

[The code and the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6uob.png)

---

How do I locate the .config folder on Windows, if it exists, and where should I create it if it doesn't? I already tried my user folder but that didn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The read_config() method in the source code tries to get the HOME environment variable, which for Windows is blank, and appends the path for the config to that. Importing os and manually setting the HOME variable to wherever you placed your .config folder seems to do the trick. You can do this with `os.environ['HOME'] = 'C:\Users\YourName'`.